# Creating a custom ItemContainerStyle for a List ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, listview, itemcontainerstyle

I'm trying to create a custom ItemContainerStyle for a ListView so that the text displayed is selectable. I'm looking to set the ItemsSource to a `List<string>`. If I were binding to a `List<Person>` (with property `Name`) I could do

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                  <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}">
                  </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

How do I specify the binding for a `List<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `<TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">` will do.

Comment: But Erno I guess, TwoWay binding of `Text` property wont work here.